# Is there a way to store custom metadata in a Google Drive file?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am writing an rsync utility for Google Drive, but I need a way of storing file system specific data about files in some sort of custom metadata tag.  I don't see anything obvious in the documentation, but wondered if there was some other facility not highlighted in their documentation; like the overloading of some otherwise unused metadata tag.  IndexableText comes to mind, but I have no idea what it is intended use is...

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files?hl=en

Comment: I have been looking at the "Comments" resource.  Seems you can associate comments with files, although they are stored separately and you would require an additional request in order to obtain the comment along with the file metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use properties: https://developers.google.com/drive/properties

Comment: I had looked at properties.  Seems to provide a good way to store generic data associated with a file, but just a shame it takes two requests to obtain the file metadata and the properties.  Unless there is an API call that will return both that I missed???